# how to handle jquery ajax success and failure correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

So I have a jquery ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'delete.php', 
     data : {
          'prd_id': <prd-id-number>
     },
     success: function(data) {
          //show success here
     },
     error : function(error) {
          //show error here
     }
 });
```

My doubt is about the `success` and `error handlers`. Is the error handler only used for `"ajax level"` error? I mean - my application can have its own error, for.e.g. the passed product id does not exist or is incorrect. Now, currently what I am passing a message back, which goes into `success()` then I have to do some internal logic to see if the message is an application error or truly success - and based on that I show the message.

is there any way I can send the message to `error()` - is that the proper way to trap and handle `ajax` errors?

Comment: For ex. you can use your own response flag at `data` (i use success field). If true — success, false — failure.

Comment: @proxyfabio I didnt fully understand what you meant...

Comment: I mean about data that you get at your `success` method. Just add `data.success` field to it. If server's response has `data.success == false` you have failure. If `data.success == true` everything is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax error can be triggered several different ways. The most common ones are , http status not being 200, timeout and data parsing errors such as incorrectly formatted json.

You can trigger the error yourself from server by returning an http response code header.

For example assume you have an API that looks up users by ID and you send an invalid ID. You can return a 404 response code header with data included that can be used in your app from within the error callback.

This allows you to set up the application code to handle both types of errors using the error callback

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you need to recall some concepts.

ajax success and error handlers are called depending upon the success or failure of the axaj call send.

success handler is called whenever the ajax call has successfully completed while error handler is called whenever the ajax call could not be completed due to any sort of error.

For your case you will have to manipulate the success handler and show the required message.

There is no way to call error handler when your ajax call has been successfully completed.

Comment: last part is not entirely accurate. Can change headers at server and trigger error callback